# R data frame Column shows multiple duplicates for same level

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one of the column named mood_scale. I imported the csv into R environment. The csv file contains only 6 levels named: Happy, Neutral, Unhappy, Very Happy, Very Unhappy, NA. However, in R its showing me 11 different levels instead of 6:

| mood_scale |
| --- |
| happy |
| Happy |
| Happy |
| neutral |
| Neutral |
| Neutral |
| Unhappy |
| UnHappy |
| Very Happy |
| Very Unhappy |
| NA |

I used the below code segment to make the changes but still shows me same 11 levels.

```
df$Mood_scale[df$Mood_scale=="happy"] <-"Happy"
df$Mood_scale[df$Mood_scale=="UnHappy"] <-"Unhappy"
df$Mood_scale[df$Mood_scale=="neutral"] <-"Neutral"
```

Comment: it is because of typos in the column values

Comment: I thought the same. But if the original csv file contains only 6 levels then it should show the same in R as well.

Comment: Data cleaning is a laborious process and will take most of your data time anyway. But you are on the right track. Won't be able to help you resolve the issue without a sample data or how you define the factor in the first place or if there are any special encoding in the character strings. Some tips though, use `tolower` to remove all capitalisation; remove leading or trailing whitespace with `trim` and replace all spaces within the string with `gsub`. Replacing of strings is more for you to know if there are double or single space.

Comment: A few things you can try is first see if there are any hidden spaces (aka spaces behind your string such as "happy ") as these would be regarded as a different string. Then the next thing is after you make the edits try refactoring the variable, because otherwise the old levels would be preserved